# How does C++ select which operator to use in if (class)?

Tags: c++, class, if-statement, boolean, operator-overloading

I have a class which mimics the behaviour of an integer. It has the following overloads:

```
class myInt
{
    ...
    operator int() const { return val; }
    operator bool() const { return 0 != val; }
    operator myInt *() { assert(0); return NULL; } // Cast to pointer not supported
    ...
private:
    int val;
}
```

When I use it as follows:

```
myInt i = 0;
if (i) ...
```

it hits the assert in the pointer cast.

Why does the C++ pick this instead of the bool operator inside the if?

Cheers,

Ian

Answer (score 0):

With further investigation, it turned out the const on the operator bool was the problem.

The compiler preferred the non-const operator myInt *() to the operator bool() const.

When I added the following overload:

```
operator bool() { return 0 != val; }
```

the code went into the bool operator instead, as desired.

Comment: It's the other way around: the **lack** of `const` on the pointer conversion is the problem. None of these functions modifies the object, so they should all be marked `const`.

Comment: The point is that the non-const cast to pointer was preferred over the const cast to bool, even though it was looking to treat the type as boolean.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The non-const operator was applied to the non-const object because it was a better match. If all the conversion operators had been const that wouldn't have happened.